# PyTorch Forecasting / PyTorch Lightning learning rate find function key error problem

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to copy the DeepAR method from the pytorch_forecasting documentation and I keep getting this problem with this piece of code.

```
# find optimal learning rate
`res = trainer.tuner.lr_find(
    net,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
    min_lr=1e-5,
    max_lr=1e01,
    early_stop_threshold=100)`
```

But I get this bug

````
File ~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_forecasting\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\connectors\checkpoint_connector.py:397, in CheckpointConnector.restore_optimizers(self)
    394     return
    396 # restore the optimizers
--> 397 self.trainer.strategy.load_optimizer_state_dict(self._loaded_checkpoint)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_forecasting\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\strategies\strategy.py:368, in Strategy.load_optimizer_state_dict(self, checkpoint)
    366 optimizer_states = checkpoint["optimizer_states"]
    367 for optimizer, opt_state in zip(self.optimizers, optimizer_states):
--> 368     optimizer.load_state_dict(opt_state)
    369     _optimizer_to_device(optimizer, self.root_device)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_forecasting\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py:244, in Optimizer.load_state_dict(self, state_dict)
    241     return new_group
    242 param_groups = [
    243     update_group(g, ng) for g, ng in zip(groups, saved_groups)]
--> 244 self.__setstate__({'state': state, 'param_groups': param_groups})

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_forecasting\lib\site-packages\pytorch_forecasting\optim.py:133, in Ranger.__setstate__(self, state)
    131 def __setstate__(self, state: dict) -> None:
    132     super().__setstate__(state)
--> 133     self.radam_buffer = state["radam_buffer"]
    134     self.alpha = state["alpha"]
    135     self.k = state["k"]

KeyError: 'radam_buffer'```
````

Comment: Have you solved this ? I still have the same error...

Comment: Yes, I've found that the PyTorch documentation doesn't list out what version they've used and their pip update has outdated their code. To fix this set pytorch_forecasting == 0.10.3 and pytorch_lightning == 1.7.0